# Copy contacts from Google to SIM card

Tags: sim-card, google-contacts

I have recently got my SIM card replaced, and lost all contacts as a result. I was wondering if there is a way to copy them from Google Contacts to the SIM card. It would type them one by one but it seems like a waste of time. Surprisingly, though, I haven't been able to find an easy way to do it. Is there a way to dump contacts from the google backup to the SIM card?

Comment: I'm confused. If you have your contacts in your Google account already, how did you lose them? Simply signing into your Google account and enabling sync should download your contacts regardless of the SIM card.  Also, even if you manage to copy from cloud to SIM, the same situation will repeat next time you need to replace the SIM card.

Comment: Yes, I can simply download the contacts to the phone, but if I want to use the SIM in another phone (an iOS or a dumb phone) I can't do that. I just wanted a way to copy those to the SIM memory.

Answer (score 1):

> You can export your Gmail Contacts list into a .csv file prior to
>   importing them into FullContact (to have a backup) using these steps:

1. Sign in to Gmail.
2. Click Gmail at the top-left corner of your Gmail page, then choose Contacts.
3. From the More actions drop-down menu, select Export.... Choose
   whether to export all contacts or only one group.
4. Select the format in which you'd like to export your contacts'
   information. Please note, some of these formats can lose some
   contact information.

   - To transfer contacts between Google accounts, use the Google CSV
     format. This is the recommended way to back up your Google Contacts.
   - To transfer contacts to Outlook, Yahoo! Mail, Hotmail, or various
     other apps, use the Outlook CSV format.
   - To transfer contacts to Apple Address Book, use the vCard format.
5. Click Export. Choose Save to Disk then click OK. Select a location to save your file, and click OK.

You probably want the vcard format. Then use a contacts app that supports vcard importing. When importing it will ask you where to save the information (choose SIM). Note SIM cards can't hold many contacts.